# How can i add polygon on google maps IOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, polygon

I want to add polygon on google maps view but I have this error

```
no visible @ interface GMSMapView declares the selector add overlay
```

Code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D commuterLotCoords[5]={
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.048019,-76.850535),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.048027,-76.850234),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.047407,-76.850181),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.047407,-76.8505),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.048019,-76.850535)
    };

MKPolygon *commuterPoly1 = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:commuterLotCoords count:5];
[mapView addOverlay:commuterPoly1];
```

Comment: The `addOverlay` method is for Apple's `MKMapView`, if you want to add polyline to your Google `MapView`, you have to declare a `GMSMutablePath` first, then add the path to a `GMSPolyline`, then add it to your `MapView`, you can see [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes#add_a_polyline) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Slight change to Dheeraj's Answer : aka Updated for **Swift 4**

```
func tempPolygons(){
    let polygon = GMSPolygon()
    let rect = GMSMutablePath()
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.546160, 73.903992))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.546099, 73.904817))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.545922, 73.905643))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.545854, 73.905973))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.545105, 73.905915))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.543153, 73.904867))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.543016, 73.903805))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.545473, 73.903863))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.546140, 73.904013))

    polygon.path = rect
    polygon.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9474907517, green: 0.2350950539, blue: 0.1785519123, alpha: 0.24)
    //polygon.strokeColor = UIColor.black
    polygon.strokeWidth = 0
    polygon.map = mapView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GMSPolygon * polygon = [[GMSPolygon alloc] init];
GMSMutablePath * rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.048019,-76.850535)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.048027,-76.850234)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.047407,-76.850181)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.047407,-76.8505)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.048019,-76.850535)];
polygon.path=rect;
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2f];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
polygon.map = mapView;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.2:**

```
 let polygon = GMSPolygon()
        let rect = GMSMutablePath()
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.7196, 75.8577))
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.7396, 75.8577))
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.7196, 75.1577))
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.9196, 76.8577))
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.9196, 75.8577))
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.7196, 77.8577))

        polygon.path = rect
        polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
        polygon.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        polygon.strokeWidth = 2
        polygon.map = mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw polygon on GoogleMap you should use GMSPolygon class. 
Steps to draw polygon:

1. Create GMSPolygon
2. Create GMSPath using co-ordinates.
3. Customize the GMSPolygon (color, width..)
4. Assign map view to the Polygon.Map property

To draw on Apple Map

1. Use MKPolygon
2. Load the co-ordinates
3. Call Addoverlay/Overlays using map view and give the paths
4. customize the rendererforoverlay

Same steps works for Polyline.